# What's the keystore file in Jetty home/installation?

Tags: ssl, https, jetty

I am currently using Jetty for http and want to open up https connectors now. I saw there is a keystore file that comes with Jetty installation under etc directory in jetty home. My understanding is that SSL certificates and keystores are something that users will create/generate and use for their servers.

Could somebody please hemp me understand -- What does this default keystore file that comes with Jetty installation contain and why will somebody ever need this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keystore file that Jetty comes with is a demonstration Keystore that is used by the demo webapps.

You are meant to create your own keystore from your own SSL certificates.

As for how to do this, see the documentation from the SSL CA (Certificate Authority) you purchased your certificates from, or from the Jetty documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that this was for the demo webapps that may possibly come with Jetty.